# Perl directories - how to locate a file

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I am trying to read this text file thats located in uploads folder. But not sure what the correct path would be. Ive tried alot of different cominations.

The text file is in this folder
      /home/username/public_html/uploads/file.text

The cgi script is in this folder
     /home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/script.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 open DATA, ("< PATH???? ");
 $line1 = <DATA>;
 $line2 = <DATA>;

 print "$line1 \n";
 print "$line2 \n";
```

I can read the file in browser directly from the server
http://www2.domain.com/username/uploads/file.txt

Comment: try this `open my $fh, '<', '/home/username/public_html/uploads/file.text' or die $!; my ( $line1, $line2 ) = <$fh>;`

Comment: Don't forget to `use strict; use warnings;`.